# Python better way of using two for loops

Tags: python, for-loop

Is there anyway I can make this easier for my self and faster?
It feels like my way of doing it is just really low and unnecessary.

Im indexing e-mail bodys and search for certain words.
I got an CSV file where I read an e-mails context out and then store it in:

```
mailwoorden = bodymail.split()
```

I got a .txt file with the words im looking for (spam words so alot).

```
strings = file.read()
```

Then I try to calculate a score with the amount of words found.
My code:

```
uitslag = 0
for i in mailwoorden:
    for a in strings.splitlines():
        test = SequenceMatcher(None, i, a).ratio()
        if test == 1:
            aantalwoordenbody = aantalwoordenbody + 1
            uitslag = uitslag + 0.5
        elif test > 90:
            aantalwoordenbody = aantalwoordenbody + 1
            uitslag = uitslag + 0.3
        elif test > 80:
            aantalwoordenbody = aantalwoordenbody + 1
            uitslag = uitslag + 0.2
        elif test > 70:
            aantalwoordenbody = aantalwoordenbody + 1
            uitslag = uitslag + 0.1
        elif test > 60:
            aantalwoordenbody = aantalwoordenbody + 1
            uitslag = uitslag + 0.05
        else:
            continue

woordenscore.append({'E-mail': testvan, 'score': uitslag})
print vandaan, "bevat zoveel woorden: ", aantalwoordenbody

woordenscoresorted = sorted(woordenscore, key=itemgetter('score'), reverse=True)
for i in woordenscoresorted:
    print i
```

It feels like the part of checking if a word from the e-mail is in the spamchecklist is not the fastest way.

Comment: `strings.splitlines()` will never return a different result

Comment: I'm confused.  `.ratio()` should return a value between 0.0 and 2.0 (IIUIC) but you test it against values like 90.  Are you sure this is correct?

Comment: You get poor performance because you loop through strings for every word in every email, and from calling strings.splitlines for every word in every email. Instead, strings should be a set (for constant time lookup) which you load once. Also woordenscore should be a heap, or use bisect, but that one's not big enough to matter unless you have a lot of messages and not many "spam words".